Return "Command Failed" when called SaveAs() method
I'm investigating an issue that one of my colleagues experiencing. Background on the issue is that we have an .net application function which opens a word document template, save the word document in a temporary folder in user's PC and let the user edit the document. Once everything is done, the document saves upon closing. However, sometimes when user open the document it leads to Command Failed error. However, this is an intermittent issue where the same user can open other documents. When I tried to isolate the issue, following code black leads to the error and I think the issue is with
masterDocument.SaveAs (AddBackslash(Settings.WorkingFolder) & fileNameString)

lead to the error. But as per my understanding the code is okay and the issue is only happening on certain documents. (Another user can open the same document without an issue)
If (myDoc) Then
    WaitForm.Message = "Saving..."
    WaitForm.masterDocument.Activate
    Call SetDocumentProperty(masterDocument, "ENVIRONMENT", Settings.Environment)
    
    ' Get the name of the output file, and if we need to add the date to it
    Dim fileNameString As String
    fileNameString = XMLData.Data.Settings.OutputName
    If (XMLData.Data.Settings.AppendDateToOutputName) Then
        If (InStrRev(fileNameString, ".") > 0) Then
            fileNameString = Replace$(fileNameString, ".", "_" & Format$(Now(), "yyyymmdd_HHnnss") & ".")
        Else
            fileNameString = fileNameString & Format$(Now(), "yyyymmdd_HHnnss")
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Save the document
    On Error Resume Next
    masterDocument.SaveAs (AddBackslash(Settings.WorkingFolder) & fileNameString)
    If (Err.Number = 0) Then
        outputFileName = AddBackslash(Settings.WorkingFolder) & fileNameString
    Else
        myDoc = False
        g_strLastError = "Failed saving document '" & fileNameString & "'. Error:" & Err.Description
        Call WinLog.Log(OBJECT_NAME, "Run", g_strLastError)
    End If
    On Error GoTo Run_Err
End If


Have you tried it without those extra parenthesis?
Like this: masterDocument.SaveAs AddBackslash(Settings.WorkingFolder) & fileNameString - Also, remove On Error Resume Next so you can see the error.

@braX it's C:\Temp. No, I have not changed SaveAs() command since the current code can save most of the documents with this code.

@braX at this point, the extension is not adding. However, at a later point, the extension is added as .docx. The name does not contain any symbols. Just A-Z and numbers. So when the error is getting it is a valid name.

You dont want to just copy/paste what the result is here when it errors? Before the Save line, add this line: Debug.Print AddBackslash(Settings.WorkingFolder) & fileNameString and then copy/paste what it prints in the immediate window to a comment here. If you removed the On Error Resume Next like I asked, it should stop there and let you click Debug.
